# Preserving superuser permissions after a factory reset

Tags: android, shell, root

I am working on an anti-theft app which makes a use of superuser permissions for some of its functionality.

The problem is, once a device gets stolen, in most cases a factory reset is going to be the first thing the new 'owner' does. This will remove any previously granted su access permissions through apps like SuperSU, Superuser and so on.

But even if, after a factory reset, the permissions to use su are not deleted, a clever thief may then manually open the SuperSU app and cancel the permission for my anti-theft app, or even set the policy to 'deny'.

My question is, is there a way to preserve the root access regardless of the state of the su gatekeeper (SuperSU etc.)? It can be assumed that during the preservation itself, regular superuser permissions may be granted.

Thanks,
fygesser

**UPDATE**

It does not seem to be possible. However, some of the pseudo-SuperUser functionality can be secured by pushing the app into /system/priv-app

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if permissions are deleted after a factory reset, but you can workaround to prevent thief to deny your permissions locking the system Settings and SuperSU app with a password